# nginx server_name directive not working

Tags: nginx

I want to use NGINX as a proxy server for my application. My application (say 'abc') is running on port 8000 on my machine. And NGINX is running on the same machine. A part of the configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.example.net;
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/abc;
    }
}
```

The configuration file when used allows me to test my app by using localhost in the address bar. However, http://my.example.net does not work. My app does not load. I get an error that the page could not be found.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Why place `my.example.net` twice on the `server_name` line? And does that hostname resolve to the system where `nginx` is running on?

Comment: Yes. The app with the actual URL is on the same machine as NGINX. I was looking for examples online to see what I was doing wrong. In some places I found the hostname repeated in the server_name directive. Using it once doesn't make a difference. localhost still works and http://my.example.net still doesn't.

Comment: I mean whether from the command line on yur client system (where you run the browser) `telnet my.example.net 80` will actually reach that system. As for the `server_name` thing: I think you overlooked that often with and without a leading `www.` is shown. Does `does not work` mean you get no connection, or the wrong content, or whatever? Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: I am really sorry for not being clearer. Unfortunately unix.stackexchange.com doesn't let anyone with a low reputation post more than one URL in one post. So I have not been clearer.

Comment: When I say that localhost in the address bar works, I mean that if I use http://localhost (i.e. 'http' + '://' + 'localhost') in the address bar of my browser, my application gets loaded.

Comment: So it works with `localhost` as the URL, but not with the real server name. That's why I'm asking whether you reach that server with that name, if the name gives an IP address not related to the server then no amount of configuration on the server will help.

Comment: Oh Thank you for clarifying. You are right. I was able to reach the real server name. So I should be using that name in the server_name directive. Either that or I need to update my server name to my.example.net. I think I understand the problem. Thank you for clarifying. I'll add an answer soon and close out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution. The solution was to use virtual hosts in NGINX. I set server_name as my.example.net in nginx.conf. And then updated my /etc/localhosts file as follows:

127.0.0.1    localhost    my.example.net

And that fixed the problem.

Comment: usually there is no /etc/localhosts file on linux machine

Comment: You probably mean `/etc/hosts`.