# How does server_name in nginx config file work?

Tags: nginx

I am following https://gist.github.com/mcxiaoke/055af99e86f8e8d3176e

```
server {
  # Git repos are browsable at http://example.com:4321/
  listen 4321 default;   # Remove 'default' from this line if there is already another server running on port 80
  server_name example.com;

  location /index.cgi {
    root /usr/share/gitweb/;
    include fastcgi_params;
    gzip off;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
    fastcgi_param GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
  }

  location / {
    root /usr/share/gitweb/;
    index index.cgi;
  }
}
```

Why is my web browser  connecting to http://example.com:4321/ forever, while can immediately connect to http://localhost:4321/?

---

I found a solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188193/674: add to my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.example.net
```

I can now connect to `www.example.net` in Google chrome browser, but not in firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com:4321. SSL
>   received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error
>   code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

and the URL in the address bar is always "https://www.example.com:4321/" when I paste `www.example.com:4321/`.

Why does the change work for Chrome? Why not for firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `example.com` resolving locally differently? Otherwise you'll be heading to an Internet site on a port that's probably not listening ...

Comment: www.example.com (on port 80) says: `Example Domain --
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.`

Answer (score 1):

You should set resolving for your host as I describe in [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495498/101265)

About `server_name` in `nginx`:
It work as option to create virtual hosts which listen to same IP and same port. And the only way to distinguish them is via hostname resolv. You can find more info about virtual hostings and `server_name` [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

You can try in firefox to write http://www.example.com:4321
Also you can check [this Q/A](https://superuser.com/q/1291062/409497)

Comment: Thanks. Why does my change work for Chrome? Why not for firefox?

Comment: @Tim, please check my edited answer