# Where is the DNS config file?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

In https://gist.github.com/mcxiaoke/055af99e86f8e8d3176e#redirecting-www-to-non-www

> **Redirecting www to non-www**
>
> Just add an "A record" to your DNS config, pointing to the same IP
>   address as the non-www
>
> ```
> Domain              IP Address       TTL  
> bdsatish.in        107.xx.yy.100    20000
> www.bdsatish.in    107.xx.yy.100    20000
> ```

where is the DNS config for me to add that record on Lubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Are you hosting your own DNS servers?

Comment: Why are you presuming that your content DNS service is on Lubuntu 18.04?

Comment: If this will not be exposed outside your network consider to use `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks. (1) Yes, it is used only on my computer, just for learning purpose. can you be specific how to do that? The format of my `/etc/hosts` is different: first IP and then domain. (2) Also I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495479

Answer (score 2):

As per comments you can define your hosts in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
107.xx.yy.100 bdsatish.in www.bdsatish.in
```

This record will add resolv of your IP address to those host names. And also resolv of those host names to IP.

Be aware the IP address should be assigned to your machine, this is not a address, reported by sites like *Whatismyip* and similar.

On Linux/UNIX you can get your IP addresses with command:

```
ifconfig
```